# Sum of all non-decreasing sequences with sum x and length k

Tags: c++

I tried to solve this problem my own, but I can't find any solution with faster time complexity for it.

I would much appreciate it if you could help me.

**Here is the problem:**

Consider all non decreasing sequences with *length k* and *sum x*. For each sequence `a1,..,ak`, we calculate the value `a1^m+a2^m+...+ak^m` (where `m` is given).

What is the total sum of this calculated sums mod `1e9+7`. Constraints: 
 `1<=n, m<=4096, 1<=k<=n`Time limit(2 seconds) Memmory limit(256 mb).

I tried to solve it by dp and define dp[i][j][u] as the answer for length i and sum j and the last number u and update my dp with all dp[i-1][j-u][x] such that x is less than u my soution works in O(n^3*k) but it can be improved by partial sum to O(n^2*k) but this is also steal much slower than what the time limit is(2 sec) because of the large constraints.
This is what i implemented so far:
https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/Kx3j7WMVSv/
Do you have any suggestions to improve my codes time complexity.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly learn how to create a [mcve].

Comment: Please, show us the code you wrote, so we can show you where exactly you went wrong.

Comment: In addition to the hints given in the answer, you should pay attention not performing redundant calculations: for example,  if two series differ by a few elements; you don't need to calculate _2k_ powers, assuming _k_ is large

Comment: You should better provide your programme inside the question, not as a link

Comment: You don't need long long type if you implement modulo arithmetic as suggested in the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are new to this site, so even though this question should be downvotted (because there is no code to show us what you have done), I decided to add something important notes since I guess you may have missed this part.

Remember, you cannot do this simply by trying to calculate `a1^m+a2^m+...+ak^m` and then mod to `1e9+7`. Because `a1^m+a2^m+...+ak^m` will be too big to keep it in any standard data types and **this is probably an important point of this question**.

In this case you need to use [Modular arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic) to calculate your result progressively. For example these will be useful for you:

```
if a ≡ b (mod n), then if a^2 ≡ b^2 (mod n) and if b^2 ≡ r (mod n) then a^2 ≡ r (mod n)

if a ≡ b (mod n), then if a*a ≡ b*a (mod n)
if a ≡ b (mod n), then if a+k ≡ b+k (mod n)
```

In addition, since `1e9+7` is prime, you can use prime number properties to progressively calculate your result. But I don't think it will be necessary here.

I won't post your answer, because you need to do most of work yourself, but you should be able to solve it correctly with this information.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear I added the code that i implemented so far and i think the problem with my code is with its time complexity do you have any suggestion to improve that.